# Run a NodeJS app with Apache

Tags: node.js, apache

I have a ubuntu server running a few apache websites. I want to run a nodejs app on the same server. I have the app running on the server now out of port 3000 (www.example.com:3000) no problems there.

I now want to direct a new domain to the nodejs app with my existing apache setup. Below is an example of the config i'm running however it's pointing to a folder. What i require is the config that points to the app's port. And any extras that I maybe missing.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin spam@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
        ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should to install [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [`mod_proxy_http`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_http.html).

Then you can use something like the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin spam@example.com
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com 

  ProxyRequests off

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```