# Wordpress and NodeJS on separate servers with htaccess

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache, ssl, redirect

I've a 2 servers with the first my website on Wordpress and the second a dedicated server with NodeJS app.

Now on 1° server I've only access to .htaccess and I don't have permission to edit apache config. On this server I've an SSL cert and use it with Wordpress.
I need to have this:
When an use type https://www.example.com/app I want to redirect all requests to my second server nodejs.example.com:3000 without change the url and using same SSL cert.
Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible without having admin access to the server. You'll need to install the apache proxy module apart from editing the configuration.

Ref: [Run a NodeJS app with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20545112/2652134)